# Create a procedure in a SQL Server transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am new to SQL Sever and I am trying to create a procedure inside in a transaction as follow:

```
        BEGIN TRY
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
        BEGIN TRANSACTION MyTran

        --*****************************************************************************         
        USE [Database]
        Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_StoreProcedure] AS

        --Some SQL Queries here
        Go

        Commit TRANSACTION MyTran
        END TRY

        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
        END CATCH;
        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

However I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

If this can not be done in SQL Server what is a workaround?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: How to create procedure?? is that your question?? Check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx

Comment: you can't create a procedure _inside_ a transaction - that doesn't even make sense - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ninesided I have multiple store procedure to create. I want them all to be create in one transaction.

Comment: Google how to create sql server stored procedure.  It can't be used that way.  You should read the documentation first before posting silly question.

Answer (score 2):

The creation of the stored procedure should be the first statement in your script. Place your stored procedure creation in a `VARCHAR(MAX)` (ie as a string), and use `EXEC sp_executesql <your_sp_creation_varchar>`

Comment: Mind that my answer is really for when the OP intended to create the Stored Procedure within a transaction (as he claims, he might not have written it properly). Not if the OP intended to use a transaction in the SP. If the latter is true, please refer to the other answers on this page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I acknowledged the solution however I am facing another problem now. I have multiple procedure to create and I need to create them all in one transaction. Is there another solution beside putting them in a varchar since the sp body is quite long and have lots of single quotes.

Comment: No. TT's solution is correct and is the way that a few tools script large deployments within a transaction.

Comment: @user1912404 There is no other way to do this but to place them in VARCHAR's and use the method I outlined. Yes, escaping the single quotes is a drag...

Answer (score 0):

**Your Syntax is Wrong**

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_StoreProcedure] AS
     SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
     BEGIN
       BEGIN TRY
       BEGIN TRANSACTION MyTran

    --Some SQL Queries here


       Commit TRANSACTION MyTran
       END TRY

       BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ;
        PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE();   -- For Debugging
      END CATCH;
      SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    USE [Database]
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_StoreProcedure] AS
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION MyTran
    BEGIN TRY

    Commit TRANSACTION MyTran
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MyTran;
    END CATCH;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer in [TSQL - create a stored proc inside a transaction statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715184/tsql-create-a-stored-proc-inside-a-transaction-statement).

user [KM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65223/km) says: 
try doing the create procedure in EXEC('...'), like this:

```
Begin Try
Begin Transaction 
    -- do a bunch of add/alter tables here
    -- do a bunch of data manipulation/population here

    -- create a stored proc
  EXEC ('create procedure dbo.test
  as
  begin
    select * from some_table
  end')
Commit  
End Try
Begin Catch
    Rollback  
    Declare @Msg nvarchar(max)
    Select @Msg=Error_Message();
    RaisError('Error Occured: %s', 20, 101,@Msg) With Log;
End Catch

GO
```